# How can I find the logs of my Cloud Composer DAG in Cloud Logging?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer, google-cloud-logging

I know this is a simple question but I find having to figure it out every time, so:

What query should I use in Cloud Logging to quickly find the logs of the DAG that I ran in Cloud Composer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the following query in Cloud Logging to quickly find the logs of your Cloud Composer DAG:

```
resource.type="cloud_composer_environment"
resource.labels.environment_name="name_of_the_env_you_created_in_cloud_composer"
labels.workflow="name_of_your_dag"
```

If you want you could leave the environment name out and just use:

```
resource.type="cloud_composer_environment"
labels.workflow="name_of_your_dag"
```